# Update different fields at same time in same column MySQL

Tags: mysql

When I try to update the name fields, I get the first result only and in the first row only by following function:

```
BEGIN

set @id1 := 2591;
set @id2 := 2594;

set @i := @id1;

SET
  @names = 'marwan,wael,adnan,sameh,';

LABEL1: WHILE (Locate(',', @names) > 0) do
SET
  @Name = SUBSTRING(@names, 1, LOCATE(',', @names));

SET @names = SUBSTRING(@names,1, LOCATE(',', @names)-1);
UPDATE employees SET NAME = @Name
WHERE
  id = @i;

SET
  @i = @i + 1;

END WHILE label1;
end
```

Attached picture:

[image]

What I need is to add all the names sequentially.
Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: [XY-problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Post the task itself. Provide source data sample (textual code-formatted CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, 3-5 rows) and desired output. Also specify precise version of your MySQL.

Comment: There's nothing to stop you adding select statements to help debug...

Comment: Why a function I would have opted for a procedure? please add create statement and inline query which invokes the function

Comment: @Akina I don't understand you brother, Can you provide more explanation?

Comment: I don't understand you brother, Can you provide more explanation?  @P.Salmon

Comment: If you don't understand the differences between functions and procedures google sql function v procedure. If your code syntaxes as published then you are not using mysql so what are you using?

Comment: Post CREATE TABLE script for the table `employees`. Post the rows values for `id` from 2590 till 2594 as INSERT INTO script.. Post needed final data state for these rows after the procedure execution. Post `SELECT VERSION();` output.

Comment: @P.Salmon No brother I use MySQL through Wampserver. Also I use procedure here

Comment: @Akina Hello brother, I own the table and it has already been created. But I need to insert data in it one column and then the next column

Comment: Either you follow our recommendations, or I can't (and won't) help you.

Comment: Please post tables as text not pictures. Thank you

Comment: Thank you bro, the problem is solved .I apologize that my English is a little weak and my experience is not great in (MySQL).  So I did not understand earlier what you were saying about table @Akina

Comment: @Kendle Thank you bro, the problem is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the update for now,inserting some debugging selects and using useful tstring functions..

```
drop procedure if exists p;
delimiter $$
create procedure p()
BEGIN

set @id1 := 2591;
set @id2 := 2594;

set @i := @id1;

SET @names = 'marwan,wael,adnan,sameh,';
select @i,@names,Locate(',', @names);
LABEL1: WHILE @names is not null and 
        @i < @id2 do
SET @Name = SUBSTRING_index(@names, ',',1);
select @i,@names,@name;
SET @names = replace(@names,concat(@name,','),'');
#UPDATE employees SET NAME = @Name
#WHERE
#  id = @i;

 SET  @i = @i + 1;

END WHILE label1;
SET @Name = SUBSTRING_index(@names, ',',1);
select 'and finally' ,@i,@names,@name;
end $$

delimiter ;
call p();

+------+--------------------------+---------------------+
| @i   | @names                   | Locate(',', @names) |
+------+--------------------------+---------------------+
| 2591 | marwan,wael,adnan,sameh, |                   7 |
+------+--------------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.003 sec)

+------+--------------------------+--------+
| @i   | @names                   | @name  |
+------+--------------------------+--------+
| 2591 | marwan,wael,adnan,sameh, | marwan |
+------+--------------------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.019 sec)

+------+-------------------+-------+
| @i   | @names            | @name |
+------+-------------------+-------+
| 2592 | wael,adnan,sameh, | wael  |
+------+-------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.023 sec)

+------+--------------+-------+
| @i   | @names       | @name |
+------+--------------+-------+
| 2593 | adnan,sameh, | adnan |
+------+--------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.030 sec)

+-------------+------+--------+-------+
| and finally | @i   | @names | @name |
+-------------+------+--------+-------+
| and finally | 2594 | sameh, | sameh |
+-------------+------+--------+-------+
1 row in set (0.041 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.048 sec)
```

Comment: You are really amazing. It has worked perfectly. You saved my life, thank you brother. I apologize that my English is a little weak and my experience is not great in (MySQL) so I did not understand earlier what you were saying in the comments. Thank you again.